# Azure VNet Point to Site VPN and OpenVPN with Azure AD on MAC

Tags: azure, vpn, openvpn

I have setup an Azure VNet and a Point to Site VPN using the OpenVPN tunnel to maintain use of the Azure AD username and password for login.

I have sample .ovpn config files but they all require certificates, beyond what is provided by Azure.

Azure provides me with the following three files:

```
AzureVPN\azurevpnconfig.xml
Generic\VpnServerRoot.cer
Generic\VpnSettings.xml
```

How should I go about using these files to configure a .ovpn document allowing me to connect to this VPN using my MacBook?

My understanding is that the certs aren't needed since we're using a username and password to login? The downloaded VpnServerRoot.cer doesn't import to the OS Keychain...

Thank for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently, MAC OS client is not available for connecting Azure point to site VPN with Azure AD authentication. The table below shows the client operating systems and the authentication options that are available to them. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/work-remotely-support

[image]

With using the OpenVPN tunnel, you can select RADIUS and Azure Certificate authentication for your MAC OS X clients. For Mac clients, Read [Configure OpenVPN clients for Azure VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-openvpn-clients#mac).

> Only iOS 11.0 and above and MacOS 10.13 and above are supported with
> OpenVPN protocol.

and [Create and install VPN client configuration files for native Azure certificate authentication P2S configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-vpn-client-configuration-azure-cert).

Comment: Alright! I was going crazy trying to figure this one out! Thanks for your help!

I'll create a second VPN specifically for Mac OS and iOS on my VNet using certificates. Thanks! :)

Comment: Just wanted to share an update to this. According to the docs this should work now using the Vpn Client from the store: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-client-mac